# Question regarding standard proof to: If f is continuous on [a,b] then f is bounded on [a,b].

Tags: real-analysis

The standard proof first builds up a sequence by saying that for each integer n there exist a number $x_n$ in [a,b] such that |$f(x_n)$| > $n$. Then, it proceeds to use the Bolzano weierstrass theorem to reach a contradiction. I understand that part and the rest of the proof but never really understood why this sequence $x_n$ Mwas bounded (since we rely on the fact it's bounded to use the BW Theorem). Can anyone give me some help here? Thank you!

Comment: Because $x_n$ is a sequence contained in $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the proof begins with the assumption that $f$ is continuous but *not* bounded. If it is not bounded, then no matter what bound we try to put on it (our $n$), we can always find a point that exceeds it (our $x_n$).

It's not the $f(x_n)$ that are bounded (because, by assumption, they aren't), it's the $x_n$. And since $[a,b]$ is compact, this subsequence converges to a point in $[a,b]$. Then the contradiction follows neatly.

Comment: Sorry, my question was actually why $x_n$ is a bounded sequence, is it because at each inductive constructive step we assume the terms of the sequence are from the closed interval [a,b]?

Comment: I am a bit lost how the compactness of the closed itnerval implies a convergence. Is there a theorem I can use? Perhaps the heine borel theorem?

Comment: Heine-Borel says "$[a,b]$ is compact". If you're using the definition "every open cover has a finite subcover", then a clean proof can be found here: http://math.berkeley.edu/~jdahl/141/141sc.pdf

Comment: In case the link dies later, the gist is: "Let $X$ be a compact space, and $\{x_n\} \subseteq X$ be an infinite sequence with no convergent subsequence. For each $x \in X$, there is an $\epsilon_x$ such that $B(x;\epsilon_x) \cap \{x_n\}$ is finite. The set of all such balls is an open cover, so by compactness, it has a finite subcover, which must contain all the $x_n$. But each of the finitely many balls contains finitely many $x_n$, so $\{x_n\}$ is finite."